# How to change background music from fragment

Tags: android, service, fragment, media-player

I would like to play a sound in background in my appliacation.
I use a service in order to manage the Mediaplayer.
I would like to know how can I change the music from a fragment.

I don't find how to do it.

Thank you
Max

the service

```
public class PlayBackgroundSound  extends Service{
     MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bbc_electronic); //select music file
        player.setLooping(true); //set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
 
}
```

the fragment

```
public class PlateauJeu extends Fragment {
   
    public int currentIndice =0;
    public static VideoView vid;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plateau_layout, container, false);

           getActivity().startService(new Intent(getContext(), PlayBackgroundSound.class));
```

Comment: Try to use bind service.

Comment: Thank you Android Killer. I've tried, but I don't kown how to do this.